# Angular: Invalid argument(s): Route generator for "..." was not included in parameters passed

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I am using child route configuration with parameters (AngularDart, package angular_router: ^1.0.2) and the following error occur:

> EXCEPTION: Invalid argument(s): Route generator for "chave" was not
>   included in parameters passed.

What Am I doing wrong?

The `@RouteConfig` definitions are:

**In Root**

```
@RouteConfig(const [
  const Redirect(path: '/', redirectTo: const ['Painel']),
  const Route(path: '/painel', name: 'Painel', component: PainelComponent, useAsDefault: true),
  const Route(path: '/empresas/...', name: 'Empresas', component: EmpresasComponent),
  const Route(path: '/iniciativas', name: 'Iniciativas', component: IniciativasComponent),
])
```

**In Parent `EmpresasComponent` (pass param to child `EmpresaDetalheComponent`)**

```
@RouteConfig(const [
  const Route(path: '/empresa/:chave', name: 'EmpresaDetalhe', component: EmpresaDetalheComponent,
      useAsDefault: true),
])
```

The problem occurs when Parent is called from Root basead config definitions, even without calling the child that has the parameter.

Detail:

Navigation should work like this:
**Root >>> Parent >>> Child (has param) = OK**

But the param is requerid here: **Root >>> Parent = Error, even no parameter is passed to the parent, only the child requires**

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason this problem.

Actually, if `useAsDefault: true` is in a route URL with parameter (p.e. /:param), this problem occurs.

The workaround is define another route URL **without** parameter as `useAsDefault: true`